# Assigning a Role Using a Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

I have a bot that creates specific roles when it joins a new server. I want to allow for the bot to assign users that role once they complete certain tasks. I do not care about the rank of the person as this is not a self role assign like many other bots. I have the role names and I have tried code such as:

```
        role = "Bronze"
        await author.add_roles(role)
```

Author refers to the person who wrote the command.
Please help.

Comment: You can't just add the role as a string, you need to use `fetch_role` to get the actual role snowflake

Comment: Please include a [mre]. You would need to use `utils.get` to get the role with that name, and then add that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch roles, as in the comments, your need

`discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles ,name='Admin')`

For example

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
       role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Cats")
       embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}, {member.name}!", description="By Joining, Your agree to the rules given in server")
       embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
       await member.send(embed=embed)
       await member.add_roles(role)
```